# Clicking anchor link makes scrolling back to top impossible as top dissapears

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink

I have been stuck with a problem with anchor links since yesterday. I have anchor links at the top of this page,: http://instabasik.com/icon-web-fonts

Whenever I click one, it skips to the anchor on the page as expected, but scrolling back to top is impossible, the top part of the page just goes missing!

Any idea why this happens? I think it might be a bootstrap bug. The page is built on bootstrap 3...

Comment: The content is there, not sure why this behavior, but is not due to clicking, if you copy and paste the url with the hashtag you get the same result. If you go to the element #leftSidebar and find the class .equalHeightCol margin-bottom: -99999px; and set it to 0, you get your sidebar back, just to point you out in some direction, you'll have to keep debugging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `row` class has `overflow: hidden;` which is causing this behavior.

Add `overflow: visible;` to the div with the `mainRow` class:

Change: `<div class="row mainRow">`

Into: `<div class="row mainRow" style="overflow: visible;">`

To fix your height problem remove the margin and padding from `.equalHeightCol`

```
.equalHeightCol {
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
}
```

Comment: Hey, I did that but noticed that the page height goes on and on now...any idea why? :-$

Comment: It's the large margin and padding on the `.equalHeightCol` class

Comment: Thank you for replying! Any idea how I can make the columns of equal height so as to work with anchor links as well?

Comment: [Here](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks) is a nice way to do equal width columns without css hacks/javasciprt

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the CSS on your site, not with bootstrap.
The `equalHeightCol` class needs to be removed from the CSS or HTML markup.

```
.equalHeightCol {
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
}
```

This code is causing the issue.  To make the table separators go all the way to the bottom after this, remove the `padding-bottom` from the `.mainRow` CSS.

```
.mainRow {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
}
```